# Liferay restrict multiple user login

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I dont want user to allow to login from the multiple pc, if user has already logged from one pc and tried to login from the another pc, the first session should be logged out,can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below portal property to achieve what you want.

```
#
# Set the following to true if users are allowed to have simultaneous logins
# from different sessions. This property is not used unless the property
# "live.users.enabled" is set to true.
#
auth.simultaneous.logins=false
```

Please note that you have to all set live.users.enabled property to true. Put these properties in your portal's portal-ext.properties file.

The first session will be logged-out when you login through different browser/machine.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. But these properties doesn't work for me. Is any thing I need to add?

Comment: Hi Pankaj,
Its working when I tried in new server. Thank You. And shall we able to display some alert kind of thing when the user logged in new system (like "You are logged in another system. Do you want to login here?")?

Comment: Can you create new question with proper details around problem or requirement?